# NodeJS Date is returning date value which is one day less

Tags: node.js, date

```
   new Date("December 17, 1995, 03:24:00");
```

Sat, 16 Dec 1995 21:54:00 GMT

```
   new Date("25/Jul/2012");
```

Tue, 24 Jul 2012 18:30:00 GMT

```
   new Date("7/25/2012");
```

Tue, 24 Jul 2012 18:30:00 GMT

Is this Ok? 
How to get correct Date based on our argument passed in Date Constructor ?

Please give your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's the timezone of your system set to? The return values you're showing are GMT and are 18 hours earlier. My guess is that you're somewhere in East Asia or Australia?

Comment: The system timezone is as per my location asia GMT+5.30, And when execute date in my shell it is giving the exact current date.

Comment: Right, but what Node.js is dumping to the console is plain GMT.

Comment: Try ``console.log((new Date()).toLocaleString())`` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Comment: Yes the Node is taking the GMT time even though the SYSTEM is configured for the GMT+5.30. Thanks:-) David my problem is solved